# Retrieve or wait for user subscription in react-router

Tags: meteor, react-router

How can I wait for user subscription in react-router? Currently, I have a function `requireAdmin` and pass it to `onEnter` to check if user is admin or not, it needs `Meteor.user()` but when I go to admin panel directly by url (or refreshing the admin page), `Meteor.user()` always return `undefined`.

I searched for this issue and I got that happens because the user subscription didn't ready at that time. I found some solution but they only apply for iron/flow router, not react-router.

Do anyone have a workaround on this?

Comment: Do you use server side rendering?

Comment: @imkost No, I'm just use client side rendering.

Comment: Would something like this help?  ```var handle = Meteor.subscribe('singlePost', postId);
    if(handle.ready()) {
     //Render other stuff here
    }```